# Missing srflx ice candidate in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: javascript, browser, webrtc, peer

I am having troubles with a webrtc app that works fine on all the PCs I test, even virtual machines, but it's not working on a Windows Server 2012 R2. I tracked it down to missing Server Reflexive (srflx) candidate on the server.

With this piece of test code (running it on a chrome dev console):

```
var rtc = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
var r = new rtc({ iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }] }, {});
r.onicecandidate = function (a) { console.log('candidate:', JSON.stringify(a.candidate)); };
r.onicecandidateerror = function(a) { console.log('error:', a); }
r.createDataChannel("");
r.createOffer().then(x);

function x(a) {
    r.setLocalDescription(a, function () {}, function () {});
}
```

On my PC, it shows something like this:

```
candidate: {"candidate":"candidate:1221703924 1 udp 2113937151 a044b6a7-4d08-XXXX-XXXX-bc858326ac0f.local 59233 typ host generation 0 ufrag IYpO network-cost 999","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}
candidate: {"candidate":"candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 111.222.333.444 59233 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 ufrag IYpO network-cost 999","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}
candidate: null
```

But on the server it looks like this:

```
candidate: {"candidate":"candidate:3704228534 1 udp 2113937151 e277d76d-XXXX-XXXX-9471-3461192326ad.local 50857 typ host generation 0 ufrag WWDW network-cost 999","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}
candidate: null
```

What could be causing the srflx candidate to be missing? Using a turn server with credentials instead of stun does the same thing. Also tried turning off windows firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing here.  Your issue is likely udp comms blocked, but mine is from running a local STUN server with no NAT in between.  A nonsense host candidate is resolved with MDNS.  Since it matches the ip of the srflx candidate, it's discarded.  If you're on a local network and can't resolve MDNS, you need a relay, which is trash.  My private ip address is 10.43.212.107. The whole world can have it. I don't give a flying monkey's arse. MDNS is trash!

5.1.3.  Eliminating Redundant Candidates

Next, the ICE agents (initiating and responding) eliminate redundant
candidates.  Two candidates can have the same transport address yet
different bases, and these would not be considered redundant.
Frequently, a server-reflexive candidate and a host candidate will be
redundant when the agent is not behind a NAT.  A candidate is
redundant if and only if its transport address and base equal those
of another candidate.  The agent SHOULD eliminate the redundant
candidate with the lower priority.

Comment: Note from [mDNS ICE draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-mmusic-mdns-ice-candidates):

"..the transport address of this candidate is an IP address and therefore distinct from the hostname transport address of the associated mDNS candidate, and as such MUST NOT be considered redundant per the guidance in [RFC8445], Section 5.1.3."  This wording has been in the draft RFC since draft-ietf-rtcweb-mdns-ice-candidates-03 published on 2019-03-25.

Answer (score 0):

That typically means UDP is blocked on that machine (the onicecandidateerror callback might provide more insight).

https://bloggeek.me/turn-public-ip-address/ has a pretty good summary on why you need to TURN/TCP and TURN/TLS in addition to TURN/UDP.

Comment: onicecandidateerror callback shows a 701 "STUN server address is incompatible." error, but it shows both in the server and my PC, so I guess it not that. UDP is not blocked. Tried `ncat -v -u -w 3 stun.l.google.com 19302` and shows "Connected to ip:port", Also tried a turn server with `?transport=tcp` and it does the same thing, no srflx on the server.